# Rails 4 Controller: Why is it creating a new object every time I refresh the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm at a total loss, I've researched as much as I can and cannot find the answer.  Here is the code below:

```
def create
  @budget_source  = BudgetSource.create(budget_source_params)
  @budget_source.update(:user_id => current_user.id)
  @budget_source.budget_segments.order(:id).each do |bs|
     bs.budget_ratios.order(:id).each_with_index do |br, i|
       br.update(scenario_id: i+1)
     end
  end
  render 'show'
end
```

A new BudgetSource is created every time I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `render 'show'`. When you submit the form, you are staying on the same page since render just renders the template. So when you refresh the page, instead of calling the `show` method, it actually calls the create method since the last action you did was a POST instead of a GET. What you should do instead is to do a redirect back to the show method with something like `redirect_to @budget_source`. Most browsers usually warn if you are refreshing a page which would cause a POST method instead of a GET.

Comment: Thanks Stepan!  I knew it must have been something very basic.  I'm reading up on the difference between redirect_to and render right now.